# Cassandra repair - recreate missing sstables only after restarting the service

Tags: cassandra

We have Cassandra v4 with 3 DCs,My keyspace is configured with RF 1 for each DC.

Node1(DC1) encountered a storage issue, leading to corruption in the files within Table T1. To address this issue, I deleted all the files from the T1 directory on Node1(DC1) and performed a repair operation on that node.

I anticipated finding the SSTables files in the T1 directory, but it turned out to be empty. Despite attempting to execute **nodetool flush** the directory remained devoid of files.

Ultimately, I restarted the service and initiated the repair process again. It was only after this restart that the SSTable files became visible in the T1 directory. Could someone provide an explanation for the necessity of restarting the service to make the repair operation effective?